# How to create new organisation and peers in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

I am using first-network sample to build my fabric network. By default it provides 2 Organisations with 2 peers for each Org. I want to create new Organisation and add more peers to these Organisations. What are the steps involved in doing this? 
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout this link from the official hyperledger-fabric docs.
[This adds an organization to the already created fabric network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/channel_update_tutorial.html)

Comment: So if I want to add Org4, should I follow the same steps?